# rtmpe url not working in jwplayer which has akamai secure streaming

Tags: jwplayer

I've been involved in a project involving securely streaming an on-demand stream from Akamai, which requires generating an auth token and passing a couple of parameters to the connect method (auth=, aifp=, and slist=).

We've tried just passing that into the akamai/rtmpe plugin as normal using them as url parameters (e.g. rtmp://mystream.com/ondemand?auth=giantokenhere&aifp=1234&slist=video/awesome).

We've tested a url using Akamai test utility but JWPlayer does not seem to be working. Does anyone know if JWPlayer supports the Akamai flavour of secure streaming?

The Secure Streaming Plugin does not seem to support it.

Here is a sample akamai rtmpe url

rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu.mp4?auth=daEbAbJdMafaCb3c7cubrb7cWahdQaYckax-brwVI8-b4-7wsXzkFjIIOFLs&aifp=v001&slist=mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu

My jwplayer setup:

```
 jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer :  "/teams/web/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
        file : mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu.mp4?auth=daEbAbJdMafaCb3c7cubrb7cWahdQaYckax-brwVI8-b4-7wsXzkFjIIOFLs&aifp=v001&slist=mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu,
        streamer : rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand,
        provider : "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf",
        type:"mp4",
        primary: "flash",
        height:"362",
        width:"600"
```

});

Should i have to set the provider here.Also,the tokens should be part of the file parameter or it should be under 
connectAuthParams:'connectionAuthToken',
streamAuthParams:'auth=livestreamAuthToken'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still have this issue? I think it because the video file name or url you wrote there doesn't contain any file format, like .mp4. I am meeting this issue too, because our server only keep the video as blob.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JW6, I believe the set up just needs to look like this:

```
 jwplayer("container").setup({
        file : "rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu.mp4?auth=daEbAbJdMafaCb3c7cubrb7cWahdQaYckax-brwVI8-b4-7wsXzkFjIIOFLs&aifp=v001&slist=mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu",
        primary: "flash",
        height:"362",
        width:"600"
});
```

Comment: Hi Ethan,I tried and it says Error loading player : No playable sources found.I am using jwplayer6.1

Comment: I did,i am getting Error loading Player : No playable sources found when i use rtmpe url.

Comment: here is the rtmpe url ---rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu.mp4?auth=daEcAdXcmaEdidEbWaIcYdDb8d8bkdyaTa_-brxEfB-b4-7ywWtkAmIKJEKq&aifp=v001&slist=mlibs/dev/CT2049_TotalVideo_FULL_G010002923399A_PulcinoPio_PuiulPiu_PuiulPiu

Comment: I want to see where the JW Player is embedded.

Comment: Hi Ethan,                                                            it is an internal app so i can't send you a link.               
            jwplayer("container").setup({
         sources: [ 
                    { file: movieUrl }
            ],
       height: 360,
          width: 640,
    primary: 'flash',
        modes: [
              { type: "flash", src:          "/teams/web/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf" },
              { type: "html5"}
          ]
   });                                       Can you try this rtmpe link,i am getting "Error loading stream:couldn't connect to server".

Comment: Looking forward for your reply ,Ethan.

Comment: I get the same error here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/wizard/, do you have an example of this RTMP url working in any other player?

Comment: Actually,i try to run the RTMPE url in http://support.akamai.com/flash/ to make sure its working fine.

Comment: I just pasted that RTMPE URL into - http://support.akamai.com/flash/, and it is not working.

Comment: can you try this.... rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mlibs/dev/MVD_000005676040_001_H264_2000.mp4?auth=daEacb1bId3cccOboaeaLctdJdFdGdic5dJ-brxZqX-ctQa-3wqVvnFlCJJEGq&amp;aifp=v001&amp;slist=mlibs/dev/MVD_000005676040_001_H264_2000

Comment: This one does work. Since this is a stream from Akamai, you might need to use this provider they wrote for the JW Player in order to get it working properly. It is available here - http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/jw/

Comment: Ethan,I tried previously with the provider : "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf".        Looks like the Akamai Plugin only supports selected streams.
 http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/jw/support_player/index.html

Comment: jwplayer("container").setup({
            file : movieUrlRtmp,
            streamer : "rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/",
            connectAuthParams : streamerUrlRtmpe,
            provider : "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf",
            type:"mp4",
            primary: "flash",
            height:"362",
            width:"600"
  });

Comment: You might be able to try JW5, as well? - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/

Comment: I couldn't download older Ver5 code from Longtailvideo's site (all support links redirect to Ver6).Can you provide the JWPlayer ver5.9 files(.js & .swf) and also tips on how to pass the Akamai's provider to the player?

Comment: and also the sample code on how to pass the provider to the player.

Comment: You can download 5.9 here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.9 , and regarding their provider, they have examples here - http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/jw/

Comment: I downloaded and i set up the akamai plugin,I am getting loaded file is not a valid media provider message.jwplayer("container").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: 'rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mlibs/dev/MVD_000005676040_001_H264_2000.mp4?auth=daEacb1bId3cccOboaeaLctdJdFdGdic5dJ-brxZqX-ctQa-3wqVvnFlCJJEGq&amp;aifp=v001&amp;slist=mlibs/dev/MVD_000005676040_001_H264_2000', provider: "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf",           type:'mp4',flashplayer:"/teams/web/jwplayer/player.swf"}],      width:640,height:360,      primary: "flash"
   });

Comment: I don't want to publish the link publicly in this forum as it's private data. Is there a way I can get that information to you via email or other private method?I can send you my screen shots too.

Comment: This is a repeatable error, whenever I get the " loaded file is not a valid media provider"
- the page loads crossdomain.xml from "providers.longtailvideo.com"
and it then tries to acquire the mp4 from "http://providers.longtailvideo.com/5/mp4.swf"
Let me what should I do to resolve this.

Comment: You are setting type=mp4 which is an alias to provider in JW5. In JW5, RTMP streaming is done like so - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31145/rtmp-streaming

Comment: rtmpe links are now running after i removed the type and flashwar.Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hi Ethan,I am getting the JWPlayer Watermark in the player.I tried hideLogo : true,it didnt get rid off that.

Comment: i have a license code,which I added as a jwplayer.key in my html file.

Comment: Going to need to see a link then ;)

Comment: Note, if you are using JW5, there is no license key, just download the licensed player from - http://www.longtailvideo.com/order/view

Comment: Hi Ethan,I have a problem now playing the audio player.Below is the code snippet...can you please help with this...

Comment: jwplayer('html5AudioPlayer').setup(
                        {
                                   playlist: [{
                                      file: 'rtmpe://cp145966.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp3:mlibs/dev/0000/898/773/b1424be0ee94553adcca6a567bbc8774/898773_2008-mlib_128K_44S_2C_cbr.mp3?auth=daEdKdwdUazdBdLaVdUbgdfdEbra4dXd2al-bsfJ1w-ctQa-7ypXxkFmHKQDJt&aifp=v001&slist=mlibs/dev/0000/898/773/b1424be0ee94553adcca6a567bbc8774/898773_2008-mlib_128K_44S_2C_cbr',
provider: "/teams/web/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf"
}], width:640, height:30 }).play();}

Comment: Can you reply for the above question,for audio(MP3) player

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Can i have a support email ,so i can email you the link...I dont want to post it for public.

Comment: I submitted to your support email,subject as rtmpe sony link.